# SELECT Выборка нескольких значений из поля

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице `mysql` есть поле `options`.

В ней есть запись со значением поля `options` `Опция1|Опция2|Опция3|Опция4|Опция5`.

Вопрос. Как выбрать эту запись задав значения `Опция2` и `Опция5`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE options like '%Опция2%' and options like '%Опция5%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете что порядок всегда растущий то можно одним махом

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE options like '%Опция2%Опция5%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM <таблица> WHERE options IN("Опция2", "Опция5")
```